# What's the difference between using has_many and using an array in ruby on rails? (Mongodb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, orm, has-many

I want to implement a few simple models to my ruby on rails project. I have the model hierarchy, Topic and Project. A Topic will contain many Projects. I wanted to know what the difference was between adding a "has_many projects" relation in the Topic model vs just adding an array field in the Topic model that stores all of the projects within it.

I am using Ruby on Rails with mongodb as my database and mongoid as the object document mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say in you're `Topic` model:

```
has_many :projects
```

Now, if you query like, `@project.topic` will execute a single query.

Let's say, you add a column in topic which stores `project_ids`, e.g.: [1,2,3]
Now if you want to find any individual `@topic` projects you need to do like this:

- first, fetch the `@topic.project_ids`
- Then, for each id query to the `Project` table, if array contains 3 values then 3 query will run.

So, all is about execution time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I'm not exactly sure what the best way is to implement this relationship. Should I have both the array and the has_many relationship. Like the following: Topic will contain "has_many :projects" and an array with all of the projects. Project will contain "belongs_to: topic".

Comment: @user5213476, I assumed that you got a separate table for `projects`. But you are listing your projects in to an array right?

Comment: In that case, I suggest you to create a new **model** named `Project` then insert the projects in to it. Then create relationship like, in `topic` model : `embeds_many :projects` and in `project` model : `embeds_in :topic`

Comment: read mongodb documentation before using mongo. You can use `has_many` but in that case the purpose of using mongo will violate. @user5213476

Answer (score 0):

***Array Store***

you can use to take reference ids of child association. eg

```
 users: 
  [
   { 
     _id: ObjectId('oii3213ui23uo')
     name: 'John',
     email: 'jhn@example.com',
     project_ids: ['oii3213ui23u1', 'oii3213ui23uo2' ,'oii3213ui23uo3']
   }
  ]
 projects:
  [
   {
     _id: ObjectId('oii3213ui23u1'), 
     title: 'Project 1' 
   },
   {
     _id: ObjectId('oii3213ui23u2'), 
     title: 'Project 2' 
   },
   {
     _id: ObjectId('oii3213ui23u3'), 
     title: 'Project 3' 
   }

  ]
```

***has_many***

You can use to embed child associations in parent document. eg

```
users:
 [
  { 
     _id: ObjectId('oii3213ui23uo')
     name: 'John',
     email: 'jhn@example.com',
     projects: [ 
      {            
        title: 'Project 1' 
      },
      {           
       title: 'Project 2' 
      },
      {           
        title: 'Project 3' 
      }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: would I run out of memory if I embed projects objects within another model?

Comment: if you embed thousands of objects within a parent doc and load once then it may go out of memory, otherwise it will be fine